# Cypress: Cypress is not able to find the Edge

Tags: cypress

I have Cypress 5.0 and Edge v84 installed on my machine. When I run

```
> npx cypress open
```

Then I set the debugger mode

```
> set DEBUG=cypress:launcher
```

Cypress is trying edge in the following location

```
     cypress:launcher looking at possible paths... { browser: { name: 'edge', family: 'chromium', channel: 'stable', displayName: 'Edge', versionRegex: /Microsoft Edge (\S+)/m, binary: 'edge' }, exePaths: [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe' ] } +0ms
  cypress:launcher found C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe ? false +1ms

      cypress:launcher looking at possible paths... { browser: { name: 'edge', family: 'chromium', channel: 'canary', displayName: 'Edge Canary', versionRegex: /Microsoft Edge Canary (\S+)/m, binary: 'edge-canary' }, exePaths: [ 'C:\\Users\\muthu\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge SxS\\Application\\msedge.exe' ] } +0ms
  cypress:launcher found C:\Users\muthu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge SxS\Application\msedge.exe ? false +1ms

      cypress:launcher looking at possible paths... { browser: { name: 'edge', family: 'chromium', channel: 'beta', displayName: 'Edge Beta', versionRegex: /Microsoft Edge Beta (\S+)/m, binary: 'edge-beta' }, exePaths: [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Beta\\Application\\msedge.exe' ] } +0ms
  cypress:launcher found C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Beta\Application\msedge.exe ? false +1ms

    cypress:launcher looking at possible paths... { browser: { name: 'edge', family: 'chromium', channel: 'dev', displayName: 'Edge Dev', versionRegex: /Microsoft Edge Dev (\S+)/m, binary: 'edge-dev' }, exePaths: [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Dev\\Application\\msedge.exe' ] } +0ms
  cypress:launcher found C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe ? false +1ms
```

But Edge is installed in different location - C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe

How can I get Cypress identify Edge?

Answer (score 0):

If you install in another location you can add it manually in the following path

```
cypress/plugins/index.js
```

You need to put the following code

```
const execa = require('execa')
const findBrowser = () => {
  
  const browserPath = {Browser Path Location}

  return execa(browserPath, ['--version']).then((result) => {
    const [, version] = /Edge Browser (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/.exec(result.stdout)
    const majorVersion = parseInt(version.split('.')[0])

    return {
      name: 'Edge',
      channel: 'stable',
      family: 'chromium',
      displayName: 'Edge',
      version,
      path: browserPath,
      majorVersion,
    }
  })
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  return findBrowser().then((browser) => {
    return {
      browsers: config.browsers.concat(browser),
    }
  })
}
```

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers#Customize-available-browsers